# I want to show that $x=\operatorname{ord}(a) \bmod m$ and $y=\operatorname{ord}(b)\bmod m$ then $\operatorname{ord}(ab)\equiv xy \pmod{\phi(m)}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

**Given:**$\DeclareMathOperator{\ord}{ord}$

$\phi(m)$ is Euler's totient function

$\ord(a)$ is the least solution of $a^t\equiv 1\pmod{m}$

$\operatorname{gcd}(x,y)=1$

$x=\ord(a)$

$y=\ord(b)$

**Show**  $\ord(ab)\equiv xy \pmod{\phi(m)}$

Comment: See, e.g., [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1962256/show-order-of-product-of-two-elements-of-a-finite-group-is-product-of-orders)

Comment: I haven't gotten to group theory yet, so I don't know what the "subgroup $<x>$" is.

Comment: That's why I didn't close the question as a duplicate. But you can pretty much ignore the group theory language.  The subgroup $<x>$ just means the collection of powers of $x$.  In your case, $<a>$ would be $\{1,a,a^2, \cdots, a^{x-1}\}$.  Calling it a subgroup just means that it is closed under multiplication and that there are inverses.

Comment: To stress:  in the accepted answer to the question I linked to, the writer just needs to claim that, in your case, the two sets $\{1, a, \cdots, a^{x-1}\}\pmod m$ and $\{1, b, \cdots, b^{y-1}\}\pmod m$ only intersect at $1$.  You can prove that statement without referring to group theory at all.

Comment: I see. I will work on that approach.

Comment: I was able to follow the argument in the accepted answer and translate it into the language of number theory without groups, mostly (see below). However, a question remains.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113401/discussion-between-anna-naden-and-lulu).

Answer (score 0):

Lemma:
**If** $a^r\equiv b^s\pmod{m}$

and $r,s<\phi$.

Then since $(a^r)^{ord(a)}\equiv 1 \pmod{m}$,

$ord(a^r)|x$

Similiary $ord(b^s)|y$.

Since $gcd(x,y)=1$, $ord(a^r)=1$ and

**Then** $a^r \equiv 1$

$a^{ord(ab)}\equiv b^{-ord(ab)}$

By the lemma, $a^{ord(ab)}\equiv 1\equiv b^{-ord(ab)}$

$x|ord(ab)$ and $y|ord(ab)$

Since $gcd(x,y)=1$, $xy=lcm(x,y)|ord(ab)$

But since $(ab)^{xy}\equiv 1$, $ord(ab)|xy$,

So we have $xy=ord(ab)$

**This begs a question:** can we have $xy>\phi$, requiring us to say that $xy\equiv ord(ab) \pmod{\phi}$ (as in the given problem) rather than saying that they are exactly equal? But $xy<=ord(ab)<=\phi$

Comment: So, you've shown that those two lists of powers only intersect at $1$, good!  Now note that, if order$(ab)=k$, we have $a^k\equiv b^{-k}$ which means that $x,y$ both divide $k$ (by virtue of what you have shown).   But since $\gcd(x,y)=1$ this means that $xy\,|\,k$.  Since the order  of $ab$ is clearly $≤xy$ we are done.