# Let $a,b\in G$, a finite abelian group and $|a|=r, |b|=s$ with $\gcd(r,s)=1$. Prove that $|ab|=rs$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

> Let $a,b\in G$, a finite abelian group and $|a|=r, |b|=s$ with $\gcd(r,s)=1$. Prove that $|ab|=rs$.

*My attempt:* Let $|ab|=n$. Since $G$ is ableian, $(ab)^n=a^nb^n=1$. Thus $r\mid n$ and $s\mid n$. Together with $\gcd(r,s)=1$, it follows that $rs\mid n$. This is where I'm stuck; need to show that $rs=n$. Any hints on how to proceed?

Edit: I've come up with a solution that is a somewhat different approach to what has been provided in the hints. Here it goes:

Since $G$ is abelian, $n\mid{\rm lcm}(r,s)$. But since $\gcd(r,s)=1$, ${\rm lcm}(r,s)=rs$ by an elementary result in number theory. Thus $n\mid rs$. Together with $rs\mid n$, we have that $n=rs$, which is what we want to prove.

Comment: Have you thought about the orders of $(ab)^r$ and $(ab)^s$?

Comment: You've shown that $n=\vert ab \vert \geq rs.$  To show equality, all you need to show is that $(ab)^{rs}=a^{rs}b^{rs}=1$.  I'm thinking you can figure that part out without too much trouble.

Comment: @lulu it's not a duplicate of that question. One answer says "anything is possible (in the non-abelian case)", and the second answer contains a statement of a more general fact for abelian groups, but with only a sketchy proof.

Comment: @lulu Is there a way to solve it using my approach directly?

Comment: @user1729  Yes, you are right.  Those answers really don't address the question at all.  I will delete the close vote while I track down a better duplicate...I'm sure the question has been answered before.

Comment: @lulu I agree, it is definitely a duplicate! If you find a target then comment here and I can use gold badge powers to close it. (Will try to find one myself too.)

Comment: @user1729   [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1962256/show-order-of-product-of-two-elements-of-a-finite-group-is-product-of-orders) is a duplicate, which is itself a duplicate.  But both it and the original appear to contain useful arguments.

Comment: @user1729 I get the answer following your hint. It was quite obvious once I got it, thank you.

Comment: @lulu The answer there is clearer than the other two, at least is my eyes, and it's not a "check my proof" question, so I closed it as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: I am struggling to understand why this question was reopened. It is clearly a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You've shown that $n=\vert ab \vert \geq rs.$  To show equality, all you need to show is that $(ab)^{rs}=a^{rs}b^{rs}=(a^r)^s(b^s)^r=1$.  I'm thinking you can figure that part out without too much trouble.